# Citation style in biblatex: (1) get rid of first names; (2) remove comma before year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biber

I'm trying to use `biblatex` and `biber` so as to have access to `@online`, etc.
But I'm quite overwhelmed.

In-text citations used to just show the last names. Now they are including first names or initials. How can I make first names/initials go away in the in-text citation?

My journal insists on (author year) rather than (author, year). Ugh, but how can I implement this for in-text citations?

Comment: What biblatex style are you using? The firstname/initials in most default styles are because the automatic name disambiguation system is probably enabled. You could set `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` as package options. However, you won't then be able to disambiguate names in citations which is sounds like you might need to do ...

Comment: My call is: `\usepackage[firstinits=false,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear-comp ,sortcites=false,natbib=true,block=space,url=false,doi=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}` after adding your two suggestions.  They solve problem (1)!  I doubt I have real disambiguation problems. It would be nice to know what biber/biblatex thinks is ambiguous (I couldn't tell).

Comment: And you still get first names/initials? If so, please say which versions of biblatex/biber you are using and also give us a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: Wow, you're fast. I pressed enter early and was still editing my reply. Thanks for the solution to (1)!. I still need to get rid of commas in citations, before the year. I don't know how to find the biblatex version. `biber --version` gives: biber version: 0.9.8.

Comment: For future reference, please always only ask one question per post. This way, other users looking for help can find solutions more easily.

Comment: @CPBL: I came here to find the answer to the second question (removal of first/given names), which isn't here, although the overall question is marked as answered. Please remove the parts of the question that haven't been answered.

Comment: @bjoseru The bad question got left as is because both parts got answered in the accepted answer.  Removal of given names is accomplished as described in the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` for the first issue but note that you then can't auto-disambiguate names if you need to.

For the comma issue, put this in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

natbib compat makes nameyeardelim into `\addcomma\addspace` so you need to reset it.

Comment: Thanks PLK! For the solution AND explanations. Both my issues are solved.

Comment: @PLK: Please don't answer a question while it violates our one-issue-per-question rule so blatantly. See [Should we answer really bad questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414) The two questions asked here aren't really terrible per se, they just shouldn't be in one post. Just imagine duplicate handling with questions like this.

Comment: @doncherry: Btw, as the offender, is there something I should do? Is it worthwhile to edit this question to restrict it to half of what I asked, and make a new one, inviting PLK to answer that too??

Comment: I still get full names in fullcite with both options turned off. How can I only get the surnames?

Comment: @Kvothe Please open a new question with a MWE