# biblatex: No comma after et al

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex for my dissertation bibliography.  The journal format I am using requires that et al, but in italic and have a period at the end.

What I have:

```
Beadle et al.,
```

What I want:

Beadle *et al*.

Also, when only two authors are present, the citation need to be like this:

```
(Beadle and Tautum 1949)
```

But what I have right now is `(Beadle and Tautum, 1949)`  (notice the comma)

I looked at the biblatex manual, but could not figure out how to go about this.  Also, search on stackexchange hasn't turned up anything useful either.  Thanks.

Comment: Both issues have been addressed already: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/4483 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65747/4483

Comment: Excellent!  I need to learn to do better searches.  Should I delete this question (if I can that is?)

Comment: You can vote for closing your own question or you can delete it.