# How to reformat in-line citations when \nameyeardelim is undefined?

Tags: citing, natbib

As per the second part of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65747/citation-style-in-biblatex-1-get-rid-of-first-names-2-remove-comma-before) question, I want to remove the comma from the end of the authors in my in-line citations, e.g.,   `Doe et al., 2013` -> `Doe et al. 2013`.  The solution is to redefine `\nameyeardelim`:

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

However, this causes

```
! LaTeX Error: \nameyeardelim undefined.
```

I'm using `natbib` with the default options.  How can I overcome this error to remove the comma between the last author and year in my in-line citations?

Comment: You should be able to use `\setcitestyle{aysep={}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `natbib` package provides the `\setcitestyle{}` command. The argument that this command takes is a comma-separated list of keywords. One of these, `aysep`, controls the punctuation between the author and the year. (See p. 12 of the [`natbib` documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) for the other keywords.)

So, to solve your problem, use `\setsitestlye{aysep={}}`.